# Why is "this" required here (extension method)?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, this, overload-resolution

*Meta note: it is impossible to search for the word "this".*

I've just run into a strange scenario in ASP.NET where the `this` keyword is required. But it's not for the purpose of resolving between local and instance variables, as you would see in a constructor.

Microsoft.Web.Mvc contains a class called `ControllerExtensions`, and I'm using the `RedirectToAction(Expression<Action<TController>> action)` overload. Maybe this is special because the overload is an extension.

`RedirectToAction(c => c.Index())` won't compile, and it says `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`. Now this sounds to me like it thinks I'm using the first overload which takes a string.

`this.RedirectToAction(c => c.Index())` compiles fine. I can also call it statically, passing `this` as the first parameter.

1. Why can't the compiler figure out that I'm looking for the overload that takes an Expression, and use that? Because the method takes an *expression* of an action, and not just an action, that must be involved. I don't understand the Expressions namespace at all, so I don't know the purpose of using this parameter type.
2. Regardless of the answer to #1, why does simply adding `this` fix everything?

Comment: Is the class a derived class?

Comment: Well, I'm in a controller, so yes. With `this`, does the compiler search my methods before checking the base class? And that would explain it?

Comment: This, BTW, is one more good reason to always use `this.` inside the implementation ;)  I know it's a controversial StyleCop guidance, but I actually think it's a good one, as it avoids odd issues like this entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extension methods work this way.

According to the C# spec (`7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations`), extension methods are only used if the call has "one of the forms":

```
expr . identifier ( )
expr . identifier ( args )
expr . identifier < typeargs > ( )
expr . identifier < typeargs > ( args )
```

This basically means you always have to have something on the left of the "." to have the compiler resolve an extension method.  The `expr.` portion *must exist* (and not be `dynamic`) for the compiler to look for an extension method.

For example, here is a small test that demonstrates:

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
    using System;

    public static class TextExtension
    {
        public static void Print(this Test test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found");
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            // Compiler error!
            Print();

            // Works fine
            this.Print();
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.Foo();

            // Fine here
            test.Print();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the compiler error - since we're inside of the Test instance, you can't call `Print()` directly without using `this.`.  However, we can easily do `test.Print()` (or `this.Print()` inside of Test).

Comment: So it's something this basic, and I never noticed? Have I really never tried to call an extension method on the current object before? Weird...

Comment: @Tesserex: It's something really basic, but rarely found.  It's rare that you use an extension method *in your own object*, since, if you're defining your own type, you can just add an instance method instead...

Answer (score 0):

I can answer #2: Your class (`this`) has only one RedirectToAction method, so there is no ambiguity. I bet if you overloaded the `String` one you'd get that error again.

Comment: @Reed: Yeah I realized that when I saw your answer. +1 btw.

Answer (score 0):

There's an ambiguity.

When you use *'this'* you invoke this method -

```
Controller.RedirectToAction
```

Without *'this'* you invoke the extennsion method -

```
Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ControllerExtensions.RedirectToAction
```

Comment: Actually, it's behaving in the opposite way. Without this, it's not using the extension overload. With this, it's correct.

Comment: @Tesserex, as far as I know, when you use 'this' you use the method on the class the method defined for, which in this case is the *Controller* class.